# Passing array from c to assembly then reversing array

Tags: c, assembly

I've been learning a lot on here but I am finally stuck and cannot seem to find the answer.  I am trying to write a simple program for class that takes a user input, puts those numbers into an array, passes those numbers and length of array to an assembly function then reverses the numbers and passes them back to the c function for output. I am having problems figuring out the address of the array on the stack, or getting the address of the last element in the edi registery.  Here is the code I have so far, please excuse the poor quality coding.  I'm new.

This is in visual studio line assembly because code blocks and eclipse keep crashing when loading and I have to get this project done.  Visual studio uses the AT&T format.

```
// String_reverse.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdio.h>


unsigned int input [8];
int length;

int string_reverse( int length, unsigned int input [])
{
_asm push ebp;
_asm mov esp, ebp;

_asm lea edi,  [esi+ecx*4-4];


_asm cmp esi, edi;
_asm jnb L_done;

_asm L_repeat:
_asm mov eax, [esi];
_asm mov ebx, [edi];
_asm mov [edi], eax;
_asm mov [esi], ebx;
_asm add esi, 4;
_asm sub edi, 4;
_asm cmp esi, edi;
_asm jb L_repeat;

_asm L_done:
_asm mov esp, ebp;
_asm pop ebp;
_asm ret;

}



int main()
{
    printf("Enter the number series you would like reversed... input -1 to 
exit\n");
scanf_s ("%u", input);


    string_reverse(sizeof(input)/sizeof(*input), input);
    printf("Your reversed number series:\n%u", input);
    getchar();

getchar();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: You're missing some very basic understanding of C and arrays. You don't read or print the array. You read a *single* value that you put in `input[0]`, then you print the *address* of `input[0]`.

Comment: Ok, thank you for clarifying.  So am I going about this whole question wrong then?

Comment: Why do you expect one of the function args to be in `esi`?  Only the x86-64 System V calling convention uses that for arg passing.  You also didn't declare the function as "naked", so using `push ebp` / `mov ebp, esp` is not appropriate either.  If you want to write functions in asm, write the whole function in asm in a separate file instead of messing around with MSVC's clunky inline asm syntax.

Comment: I'd love to use something else other than MSVC, but unfortunately I can't get anything to run correctly on my laptop.  Eclipse crashes because of some known bug in Java and codeblocks keeps going crazy.

Comment: You need loops for the input and output.

Comment: MSVC probably has an option to compile C code to assembly code. Then you can write your `reverse` function in C, compile it to assembly and try to read and understand the assembly code generated by the compiler.

Comment: MS VS used to have MASM included (with MSCC), so you could easily use stand-alone ".asm" files for writing pure asm procedures. (not sure how exactly it is packaged today, haven't seen VS for like 15 years, but I guess it's still part of the package, or maybe it's now optional checkbox during installation, but I'm pretty sure it must be buried somewhere, as the 64b MSCC doesn't support inline assembly any more, so in case you really need assembly, the stand-alone asm file assembled by MASM is then natural choice (or reconfiguring the VS project in advanced way to make it use other assembler)).

Comment: And your asm syntax is "Intel", "AT&T" is the other one (used by GCC and clang by default).